# Java - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: create a URL from User Input using JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am building a GUI to retrieve historical weather data. I have 2 JFrames, the first frame asks the user to enter a date for which he/she wants to retrieve the given weather data.

On clicking the OK button, the data should be passed on to an urlString and the weather data should be retrieved from that URL and displayed on a second frame.

Code in frame1:

```
okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String s = event.getActionCommand();
        if (s.equals("OK")) {
            String a = (String) airportBox.getSelectedItem();
            String d = (String) dayBox.getSelectedItem();
            String m = (String) monthBox.getSelectedItem();
            String y = (String) yearBox.getSelectedItem();
            String urlString = frame2.makeURL(a, y, m, d);
            frame2.openURL(urlString);
            frame2.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Code in frame2:

```
public void openURL(String urlString) {
    try {
        // Open connection
        URL u = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = u.openConnection();

        // check to make sure the page exists
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
        int code = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
        String message = httpConnection.getResponseMessage();
        System.out.println(code + " " + message);
        if (code != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            return;

        // Read server response
        InputStream instream = connection.getInputStream();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(instream);
        //use comma to separate values
        in.useDelimiter(",");

        /* 
         * Store Weather Data in ArrayList
         */
        // display server response to console
        WeatherData data = new WeatherData();
        ArrayList<String> weatherData = data.getWeatherData();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String input = in.next();
            weatherData.add(input);
        }

        int averageTemperature = data.calculateAverageTemperature(weatherData);
        Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();

        //add Label at the Top
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 2));
        contentPane.add(graphImage, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JLabel temper = new JLabel("Average Temperature: ");
        JTextField tempField= new JTextField(String.valueOf(averageTemperature));
        tempField.setEditable(false);

        centerPanel.add(temper);
        centerPanel.add(tempField);
        contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
    catch (IOException i) {
        System.out.println("Can't display page " + urlString);
    }
}

private JPanel centerPanel;

public String makeURL(String a, String y, String m, String d) {
    String urlString = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/"+a+"/"+y+"/"+m+"/"+d+"/DailyHistory.html?HideSpecis=%201&format=1";
    return urlString;
}
```

the `openURL()` method seems to cause the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "temperature history"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
at WeatherData.calculateAverageTemperature(WeatherDataTest2.java:171)
at WeatherGraphFrame.openURL(WeatherGUITest.java:227)
at WeatherGUIFrame$1.actionPerformed(WeatherGUITest.java:133)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I hope you get the basic idea. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong: you're trying to parse the String, `"temperature history"` into a double number, something that logically doesn't make sense. Note that the String is no-where to be found in the code you've posted suggesting that you may not be showing us the correct code, but understanding the error should help you to fix it, I think. Note you should indicate for us which line is `WeatherDataTest2.java:171` since that's the line that causes the exception to be thrown.

Comment: So, regarding, `"I hope you get the basic idea. Let me know if you need more information."` -- the information is as I mentioned above, and yes, if you still need our help, you may want to post more information, including where that String, `"temperature history"` came from, where you're trying to parse it, and what is going on at line 171 of WeatherDataTest2.java

Comment: Can you please post the method `calculateAverageTemperature`? And I hope you haven't forgot that you need to skip the first line of that weather data, since the first line contains the column names.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in the above comment, you are reading the input from the HTTP request and expecting a numeric value or values.  Instead the request returns a text string "temperature history".  I looked at this site, and think there is a flaw with your approach.  The URLs that you are submitting return HTML pages.  These pages have the weather history you are looking for - however they also contain HTML for formatting this data in the browser.

Extracting data from HTML is known to be a bad practice.  The problem is that you have no control over what the structure of the HTML will be.  The site could change it at any time.  The solution to this is to call a pure API if one exists.  In this case, it appears that the site does support a REST API.  See: http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/ for details about how to do this.

So I suggest you change your code to call the REST API instead.  Thus your program will received data in a guaranteed, known format.  It looks like you have the choice of receiving either XML or JSON.

Comment: Actually, the URL with the parameters she passed is not formatted as HTML but as CSV. Well, nearly.

Comment: That is not what I am seeing.  When I send a request to *http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/LAX/2014/12/21/*, I get an HTML page.  I verified this in both the browser and with curl.  Am I using the wrong URL?

Comment: Yep, you forgot the parameters after the `?`. [This is the link](http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/LAX/2014/12/21/DailyHistory.html?HideSpecis=%201&format=1). Admittedly, it contains `<br/>` at the end of each line, but you *could* say it's a predictable format.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the error occurring was unexpected input data retrieved from the link, such as "calm" instead of wind speed 0.

I have added exceptions to deal with unexpected data and the program works fine now!
Thanks to everyone who replied!